# Comparative statics at fixed point of system

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $w(x,y)=\frac{\log(\Lambda+\xi)-\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\Lambda-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\Lambda^2-4\frac{x-y}{\zeta}}\right)}{\log(\Lambda+\xi)-\log(\Lambda-\xi)}$ for $\Lambda>0$, $\xi>0$, $\xi\in\left(\frac{\Lambda}{2},\Lambda\right)$, $\zeta>0$.

Let $x^\star$ and $y^\star$ solve
$$ x^\star = \max_x x w(x,y^\star)$$ and
$$ y^\star = \max_y y \left(1-w(x^\star,y)\right)$$

If $\frac{\partial w}{\partial \Lambda}>0$ (which is equivalent with setting $x^\star>y^\star$), I need to show that $\frac{d w\left(x^\star, y^\star\right)}{d \Lambda}>0$.

Comment: I got to a point where: $$\frac{\partial w\left(x^\star,y^\star\right)}{\partial \Lambda}=\frac{1}{(x^\star+y^\star)^2} \left(\frac{\partial x^\star}{\partial \Lambda} y^\star - x^\star \frac{\partial y^\star}{\partial \Lambda}\right)$$

Comment: I could also show that $\frac{\partial x^\star}{\partial \Lambda}>0$. My numerical work indicates that $\frac{\partial y^\star}{\partial \Lambda}$ seems to be negative, which means that I need to show: $$-\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{\partial w}{\partial \Lambda}+\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} \frac{\partial w}{\partial \Lambda} (x^\star+y^\star) + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y\partial \Lambda}(2y^\star+x^\star)<0$$.